# how to disable jenkins autorun in windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, autorun

I have installed Jenkins on my PC with Windows 10. And every time when I run my PC - Jenkins runs automatically too.
I couldn't find any config file in Jenkins folder when i can disable automatically  run.
Thanks.

Comment: It is a Service. You has to put the serve to start manually

Answer (score 24, accepted):

run 'services.msc' from the command line.

Then find the service called Jenkins.

Select this, right click select properties and select start manually from the drop down list, or disable it if you prefer.

[image: Startup type of service]